# When to use reducer in storing data in a Redux app

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm quite new with Reactjs so I would like to ask what are the scenario where you would store data in reducer. For example if you have a list of data in a store and would like retrieve an item from the lists. Will it be efficient to just a request a get API call to fetch the item? I don't know if my scenario is right but Would like to ask some real world scenario that has been use in your application.

Comment: Reducers are for storing procedures, not data. I recommend you just find some good Redux tutorial in your native language because I don't really understand your question.

Comment: This is a hard question to answer as the specifics of how to use Redux depend on your app structure, target users, etc. I'd start by reading the Redux docs http://redux.js.org/ and check out this Medium post for insight as to whether or not you should use Redux at all. https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367